# Ad removal for premium subscribers in Android YouTube Player API

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am using YouTube Android Player API version 1.2.2 by importing it as a jar file on Android.

**For my users who are subscribed** to YouTube Premium,
I want to remove the ads that appear before the YouTube video plays.

Is there a function already provided or is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

They would have to sign in with their account, so it's probably not possible without doing a lot of ground work for them to sign in...

Comment: I want to make it. Where can I find out how to implement the YouTube login function and apply advertisements removal  to the player?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, but this should point you in the right direction. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8sGdPi86NI